# detect from a server (by Javascript) that OCX is already installed(with regsvr32) at client machine

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, ocx, browser-addons

I have developed an ActiveX control as an OCX component and I register it with regsvr32 in client side.
I have developed a local server (e.g tomcat) that when the user connects to it, first of all I want the server to detect whether the user which is connecting with IE browser has already registered the OCX or not. I am looking for such a code written in java script. 
As I searched, I found this code but when calling navigator.plugins.length 0 is returned and no plugin is detected (although I can call the OCx by its UID in javascript.  Is there any code to detect whether an OCX component is registered in IE.
furthermore when I open the "manage add-on" in IE, I can not see my OCX there. why is it like that?
Best Regards.

Comment: How exactly do you “call the OCX by its UID in JavaScript”?

Comment: <OBJECT ID="MyActiveX1" CLASSID+"CLSID:xx....">

Comment: That doesn’t really look like JavaScript.

Comment: I call it in javascript as : var result=MyActiveX1.add(2,3);

Comment: Alright, so what if you check for the existence of `MyActiveX1` — `if(MyActiveX1){/* it is installed */}else{/* it’s not installed */}`?

Comment: Dear @ Xufox since MyactiveX is an object, the below statement is always true, even though I call myactiveX1 object with a wrong classID.